# How to solve this Grouping issue in JasperReport?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using group functionality in my jasper report to group data . Grouping is happening fine.But the problem is if next group comes, then data will be populated in the next page,even there will be lot of space in the previous page.likewise for each different group different pages coming instead of coming continuously.Can any one help me which property i need to change to populate data continuously even different group comes.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are setting the resetType as Group. Thats why it is coming in the second page.
Change the resetType as None.

Comment: Hey Purushotham, Really thanks its working. And i have another doubt..Can you please clarify. Actually i am using two subreport inside the detail band of my main report. My problem is that detail band height is not dynamically changing.If the subreports datasource returns more values then according to that detail band is not growing.

Comment: It depends on the height what you gave for the individual report which are sub reports.

Comment: Yes, remember it will use the space you set aside for each element you put in the detail band.  You can shrink it down and tell it to grow and elements below it to float.